# .NET 6 & Cosmos DB: How best to return a different type T2 from container.CreateItemAsync<T1>(t1)?

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb, .net-6.0

#### Background

Using .NET6 with Cosmos DB v4, I can create an item in a container like so:

```cs
Container container = client.GetContainer(config.GetValue<string>("CosmosDatabaseName"),
                    config.GetValue<string>("CosmosUsersContainerName"));
NewUser createResponse = await container.CreateItemAsync<NewUser>(newUser);
```

The thing is, `container.CreateItemAsync<NewUser>(newUser)` seems to only be able to return the `NewUser` type, but I want to return type `User`.  `User` has all the same fields as `NewUser`, plus `lastCheckedDate` and `accreditationInProgress`.  Writing this:

```cs
User createResponse = await container.CreateItemAsync<NewUser>(newUser);
```

returns

```
CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.ItemResponse<QualityManagement.CreateUser.CreateUser.NewUser>' to 'QualityManagement.CreateUser.CreateUser.User'
```

#### Question

How do I easily cast the result of `await container.CreateItemAsync<NewUser>(newUser)` to type `User`?

#### Possible backup options

If I can't return a different type, as far as I can see I have 3 options:

1. Make a second constructor in `User` that takes a `NewUser` object,
2. Simply `await container.CreateItemAsync<NewUser>(newUser)` and have a second method that queries the db for the new User, however that will be rather verbose.
3. Make `User` inherit `NewUser`, but that seems messy, especially as I want to keep each object immutable.

##### C# Objects

```cs
public class NewUser
{
  public string Id { get; internal set; }
  public string FirstName { get; }
  public string Surname { get; }
  public string Email { get; }
  public string AccreditationManagerId { get; internal set; }
  public string AccreditationManagerName { get; }
  public string Role { get; }
  public WorkArea WorkArea { get; }

  public NewUser(string firstName, string surname, string email, string accreditationManagerId, string accreditationManagerName, string role, WorkArea workArea)
  {
    FirstName = firstName;
    Surname = surname;
    Email = email;
    AccreditationManagerId = accreditationManagerId;
    AccreditationManagerName = accreditationManagerName;
    Role = role;
    WorkArea = workArea;
  }
}

public class User
{
  public string Id { get; }
  public string FirstName { get; }
  public string Surname { get; }
  public string Email { get; }
  public string AccreditationManagerId { get; }
  public string AccreditationManagerName { get; }
  public string Role { get; }
  public WorkArea WorkArea { get; }
  public DateTime LastCheckedDate { get; }
  public IEnumerable<AccreditationInProgress> AccreditationInProgress { get; }

  public User(string id, string firstName, string surname, string email, string accreditationManagerId, string accreditationManagerName, string role, WorkArea workArea, DateTime lastCheckedDate, List<AccreditationInProgress> accreditationInProgress)
  {
    Id = id;
    FirstName = firstName;
    Surname = surname;
    Email = email;
    AccreditationManagerId = accreditationManagerId;
    AccreditationManagerName = accreditationManagerName;
    Role = role;
    WorkArea = workArea;
    LastCheckedDate = lastCheckedDate;
    AccreditationInProgress = accreditationInProgress;
  }
}
```

#### References

I found https://joonasw.net/view/exploring-cosmos-db-sdk-v3, but it didn't help.

Comment: I'm not massively familiar with Cosmos DB, but does this behave the way you'd expect for your DB structure? I think this would create a 'NewUser' object, but unless you've set it up somehow, why would the database think to model that as a 'User' object? I've not worked with Cosmos DB before, but this looks a bit like EF Core, and I know this wouldn't fly. (In which case, I'd expect the method above to have an override to take a type argument of your expected type that you can use)

Comment: I guess my question is why don't you instead delete the 'NewUser' object, and just create the 'User' item you want returned and give default values to your 'LastCheckedDate' and 'AccreditationInProgress'

Comment: So you think this is a frame question?  I'd built out this solution from an API spec my team and I put together, and it referenced one user type for the create user request, and another for the corresponding response.  I'd not thought to re-use the main User object.

Comment: Please do not use the V4 SDK, use the V3 SDK instead. The V4 SDK is a preview SDK and hence not meant to be used on production.

Comment: Yeah exactly, why would you want to have two resources that describe the same thing? Don't get me wrong maybe that's necessary, but if it's not, it's just extra work.

Comment: @DubDub if you want to post an answer saying what you've said above, then I'd be happy to accept that as an answer.